# How to create a sequence starting with a character and then with numbers in R

Tags: r

How to create a sequence starting with a character and then with numbers in R

I wanna to create a sequence like the following:
y1998 y1999 y2000 till y2011

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's `:`:

```
1998:2011
```

And `'` or `"` to create string constants:

```
'y'
```

And `paste0` to concatenate both:

```
paste0('y', 1998:2011)
```

Note how the `paste0` function is applied to the second parameter, element by element. That's one of R's strengths.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. But the right code is paste("y",1998:2011,sep=""). But still thank you

Comment: @user2408728: That depends on your R version indeed. `paste0` is available as of R 2.15, I think: http://simplystatistics.org/2013/01/31/paste0-is-statistical-computings-most-influential-contribution-of-the-21st-century/. Otherwise you need to use the `sep` argument, as you have noticed correctly.

Comment: The switch to R using `paste0` happen in the R 2.14 (a while ago).  You may want to consider updating at least to R 2.15.x